# Complement of a maximal direct factor is indecomposable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-algebra, representation-of-algebras

Reading a book I saw the following assertion:

> Let $R$ be a ring (*not necessarilly commutative*) and $\varepsilon$ be the poset (w.r.t. inclusion) of all internal direct factors of an $R$-module $M$. If $M_1$ is a maximal element of $\varepsilon$, then its complement $N_1$ is a minimal element of $\varepsilon$ and hence $N_1$ is indecomposable.

**My question:** But I don't see how that fact that $M_1$ is maximal implies $N_1$ minimal in the poset $\varepsilon$. Any hint on how to show this ?

I tried to show that $N_1$ is indecomposable as follows:

Suppose that there exists two submodules of $N_2\neq 0$ and $N_3\neq 0$ such that $N_{1}=N_2\oplus N_3$. Then,
$$M=M_{1}\oplus N_1=M_{1}\oplus(N_2\oplus N_3)=(M_1\oplus N_2)\oplus N_3.$$
but $M_{1}\subsetneqq M_{1}\oplus N_{2}$ as $N_2\neq 0$ and this contradicts the maximality of $M_{1}$. So, $N_{1}$ is indecomposable.

Comment: Your proof also shows that $N_1$ is minimal: if $N_1$ were not minimal, it would contain a proper submodule which was also a direct factor of $M$, and thus $N_1$ would be decomposable.

Comment: Can we prove directly that $N_1$ is minimal dans $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: I mean can we show somehow directly that $N_1$ is minimal from the fact that $M_1$ is maximal dans  $\varepsilon$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comments:

Your proof also shows that $N_1$ is minimal: if $N_1$ were not minimal, it would contain a proper submodule which was also a direct factor of $M$, and thus $N_1$ would be decomposable. – KReiser 14 hours ago